# How to determine actual cost of specific spot instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to know how much a specific spot instance is actually costing? My only idea is to give it a specific tag and wait to see it show up in the billing report. But what I really want is to to know in "real time" how much each spot instance is costing.

Answer (score 2):

From [Amazon EC2 Spot Instances Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/):

> The following table displays the Spot price for each region and
>   instance type (updated every 5 minutes).

So one (crude) option would be to parse that page to get the price matching your particular instance type and region.

I don't know if the equivalent info is available via the [AWS Price List API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html):

- [the Bulk API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/using-ppslong.html) clearly doesn't support it:

> Offer files do not include information about expiring free tier offers
>   or Amazon EC2 Spot Instances.

- the spot instace pricing isn't explicitly declared as unsupported in [the Query API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/using-pelong.html), so there *might* be a chance for another option here, that'd be better than parsing pages. But I didn't try - I'm not an AWS user yet.